# Why '&' reference in not required in classes in C++?

Tags: c++, class, object, scope, reference

in the following code for swapping by call by refernce is used

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void swap(int& c,int& d)
{
    int temp;
    temp=c;
    c=d;
    d=temp;
}

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    cout<<" Enter value of a";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"\n Enter value of b";
    cin>>b;
    swap(a,b);
    cout<<"a: "<<a;
    cout<<"\n b:"<<b;
    return 0;
}
```

but if i use class and make object then there is no need of '&' refernce in calling the method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

class swapy
{
public:
    int a;
    int b;


    void swap(int c,int d)
    {
        int temp;
        temp=c;
        c=d;
        d=temp;

    }

};

int main()
{
    swapy s;

    cout<<" Enter value of a";
    cin>>s.a;
    cout<<"\n Enter value of b";
    cin>>s.b;
    swap(s.a,s.b);
    cout<<"a: "<<s.a;
    cout<<"\n b:"<<s.b;
    return 0;
}
```

Can you explain how this worked?Why & was not needed in the second program.

Comment: The second program appears to be taking advantage of `std::swap` and not calling your method at all

Comment: The two programs simply do not do the same thing.

Comment: This function `void swap(int c,int d)` does nothing. The arguments are local copies to the function and the actual c and d are not altered.

Comment: your `swapy::swap` is broken because you dont use the `&`, you just dont call that function

Comment: And this, boys and girls, is a text book example of why you do not use `using namespace std` in your program.

Comment: To modify parameters, passed to a method or function, you either pass them by reference or by pointer.  Passing by reference is safer than passing by pointer.  You member `swap` function is passing by value or copy, so you will only modify the copy, not the original variables.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you are not calling your class `swap()` function, because you are not calling it with your class object s, for class `swap()` function you have to call it with s. like

```
s.swap(c,d);
```

Further Change your function `swap()` name to any other name like `mySwap()` then you'll get to know that this is not correct, because `swap()` is a built-in function of `std::`
so it will be simple to understand if you change the name of your function.

Furthermore, you are not using class member variables correctly, you have to do something with your class member variables a and b. your class is useless here.